# How to go from text to an RDF triple on Freebase?

Tags: python, graph, rdf, freebase

I'm trying to work with Freebase database and I'm having difficulty understanding how they encode each word. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/freebase): `"In Freebase, objects have MIDs that look like /m/012rkqx. In RDF those MIDs become m.012rkqx. Likewise, Freebase schema like /common/topic are written as common.topic"`.

If I understand correctly, the library [RDFLib](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gettingstarted.html) is used to work with the RDF triples.

Say I have a word `Penguin`. How can I get the corresponding encoding that was used on the graph? That is, the MID/URI/RDF object/subject that is used to encode `Penguin` on the graph. I'm trying to find the corresponding triples to specific words, but I don't know their encodings so I can't look them up on the graph.

Comment: how do you work on Freebase? Did you load the dump locally?

Comment: @UninformedUser I didn't do it locally. I found several Python libraries that allow you to query from it. Will the method change if I do it locally or using a query? I thought that it's the same graph

Comment: can you give a reference to a query service you are using please? And no, as long as you're processing the same RDF dump nothing is different. I'm just wondering who is hosting such a service

Comment: regarding your example, `http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.05z6w` would be the URI for penguin. I looked it up via DBpedia, go to https://dbpedia.org/page/Penguin and check for `owl:sameAs` links. It also holds Freebase mapping for a bunch of queries.

Comment: I'm looking for a Python method that can give the URIs. I have several of them and I can't go to the website for each one manually. Working on giving you that reference

Comment: I'm doing exactly the same thing. I need to link word in a text to freebase entities. Since FB was deprecated I try to switch to Wikidata.
I create simple function to convert Freebase MID to Wikidata ID: [here](https://github.com/matteomedioli/Transformers-KBDriven/blob/0afc6924d86e0571f4c110796f54e966aedd9b18/utils.py#L250)
and a method to retrieve Wikidata data from a word in string format: [here](https://github.com/matteomedioli/Transformers-KBDriven/blob/0afc6924d86e0571f4c110796f54e966aedd9b18/utils.py#L283).

I need to understand how to apply WordSenseDisambiguation in Wikidata.